# how to add mindmap file to wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, mindmap, freemind

I am creating mindmaps with the help of freemind tool and it provides me a facility to store it as mm file extension.
do we have any way by which I can embed it in WordPress website as clickable way and not as an image

Answer (score 0):

I did some researches apparently there's a plugin called "FreeMind WP Browser".
But please be aware I saw that the last update of this plugin was 8 years ago, it may present some vulnerabilities.